# Close an application If run time exception occurs using Robotium

Tags: android, robotium

I have a testcase like I want to crash the application at run time. As user clicks on upload button, activity starts uploading/fetching  the data to USB pendrive that's attached to my android tablet. So

**once the upload operation starts,the application should get closed automatically if run time exception occurs.**

How can we write a testcase for this using Robotium?

Help and sugesstions are always appreciated,

Thanks

Here is my sample code.

```
   solo.clickOnMenuItem("Upload");
   solo.sleep(1000); 
   solo.assertCurrentActivity("some message", SomeActivity.class);
```

Comment: Please clarify what you want to achieve - simulate runtime exception, handle that exception or something else?

Comment: @maszter , Yes Its something like simulating the run time exception,I mean If run time exception occurs the application should get closed automatically.If I want to test this scenario in my application what should I do?

Comment: @maszter, any Idea on this? Just want to simulate runtime exception.